# Parse String into JavaScript Syntax

Tags: java, database, string, parsing, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a JavaFX Application, which requests a Series of Numbers(lat & lng) from google maps api.

And the Gmap api returns the values in the form:

> 60.06484046010452,-121.640625,50.064191736659104,-136.40625,50.958426723359935,-103.7109375

And i'll be storing this in the database as a String(VARCHAR2), because the number of values being returned would be dynamic, according to the user input in the Application.

So, in here i want to parse, this String(when it'll be retrieved from the Database), into this :

> [
>       {lat: 60.06484046010452, lng:-121.640625},
>       {lat: 50.064191736659104, lng: -136.40625},
>       {lat: 50.958426723359935, lng: -103.7109375}
>     ];

I mean, i want my java program, to automatically add those lat & lng keyword to the alternate Values(with the Colon), and the comma's in between, i want my program convert that string retrieved from the database into the form(containing lat & leg keyword, curly braces, commas ), upon retrieval from the database, and then save this modified string into some string variable, How can i do this ?

Basically I'm not Sure, which Technique, or API's I can Use or Implement in my program, to Manipulate the String(so, as to Change its format, into Something what I can pass to Google Maps API's), Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [JSON](http://www.json.org) writer using a JSON library, such as [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)'s [JSONWriter](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONWriter.html) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).  You could also just code it using iteration and StringBuilder, but using a library is probably preferred for this task.  Refer to the documentation for your chosen library on how to use it.  Review [basic string processing in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html) if you need further information on parsing and working with Strings.